# How can I malloc 8*10^9 int memory?

Tags: c, gcc, malloc, dynamic-arrays

I need an 8*10^9 int array....
I know there is a limit how much memory a program can malloc (SIZE_MAX) but is there a way to change it ?
I'm using gcc 4.6(mingw).
Thx in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int i,j;
int m=2000*2000,n=2000;
int ** matrix;

matrix = malloc(m * sizeof(int *));
for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
matrix[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
puts("check point1\n");
for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        matrix[i][j]=5000;
puts("check point2\n");
int * matrix2;
matrix2 = malloc(m * sizeof(int ));
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you split it into multiple parts?

Comment: you do realize that's 32GB of RAM, right ?

Comment: yes but if there's a way i would like to avoid it

Comment: you do realize that's 32GB of RAM, right------yes, i think the program will use hdd space

Comment: Does your machine have 40+ GB of RAM? You'll apparently need 32GB for your array alone... then you still need memory for your OS and programs.  *(in otherwords: whatever task you're doing, the **wrong** way is to allocate 32GB)*

Comment: the program is for scientific purpose i can't avoid 8*10^9

Comment: @user1740587 What operations are you doing with that array?

Comment: I will fill it with -1 then add integers from the 0 point then read elements with [] operator.

Comment: if you need to allocate 32 GB in one malloc you know you are doing something wrong

Comment: if you need to allocate 32 GB in one malloc, you are probably working with "big data" ... and you should be using a 64-bit system where SIZE_MAX is 2^64-1

Answer (score 1):

If you have a sufficient block of address space available (No chance for 32Bit code), you might be able to allocate that much memory (Might use swap-space though).
Trouble is, `SIZE_MAX` is the maximum value of `size_t`, which is nearly always sufficient to encompass the whole address space.

There are multiple ways to go about it if that's not the case:

1. Use `malloc()`: Many `malloc()`-implementations directly hand out pages when an allocation is more than some specific number of pages.
2. Go directly to the platform api yourself. `mmap()` or something alike is what you need.
3. If the data is already in a file in useable form, consider mapping that file directly into your address space. (Can be a variation of method 2)

   - Map read-only if you don't need to change the data.
   - Map copy-on-write if you do not want to change the file but have to modify (part of) the data.
   - Map read-write if you want to modify the original file. Consider making a backup before you test your program on it.

If it is the case, create some file which is big enough to hold it all and map views to the parts you actually use just then.

Answer (score 1):

If you have enough RAM *and* you are on a 64-bit system, you should be able to allocate it in one big chunk. If either condition is not met, then you are in trouble. There is no sensible way to operate on such a large array on a 32-bit system, and there is not much sense in trying to operate on an array that does not fit into memory. If `SIZE_MAX` is not large enough, `SIZE_MAX` is only the symptom, not the cause.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `malloc` more than `SIZE_MAX`. If your system actually supports your process allocating more than that amount, you'd have to do it via multiple calls to `malloc`, each of which requests no more than `SIZE_MAX`.

Of course you could also look into using a different compiler that has a larger `SIZE_MAX`.

NB. The C standard is unclear on whether `calloc()` is allowed to have the product of its arguments exceed `SIZE_MAX`, and if so, whether it is supposed to allocate a larger chunk than `SIZE_MAX`. Since it is unclear, IMO it would be best to not attempt this. I have heard that some C library implementations just multiply the arguments using a `size_t`.

Comment: Well, you certainly _can_ allocate more than `SIZE_MAX` simply by not using `malloc` at all, but `mmap`. Mapping a 32GiB file is no issue on a 64bit system. Whether that makes sense (performance-wise) is a different matter.

Comment: @Damon OP only stated you can't do that with malloc, which is correct.

Comment: Since `size_t` is intended to be a type capable of representing the size of any object, `calloc` should not allocate more; the representation array for the object obtained by `calloc` has type `unsigned char [nmemb*size]`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is more basic than that.  Assuming your machine has enough memory to hold the array in RAM (otherwise you will be paging/thrashing to disk) you need to be able to address it.  You need a 64-bit OS and environment.  Try [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/).

The biggest motivation to use a 64-bit system is the increase in the address space.  Yes, on a 64-bit system you can add two 64-bit operands in a single instruction instead of dealing with the lower 32-bits and then the upper 32-bits.  So it takes you two instructions on a 32-bit system to add two 64-bit operands... not a huge deal.  However, having more than 32-bits of address space, that is game changing, now you can tackle large problems that you simply could not address in a 32-bit system.

Your machine could have 128 GB of RAM, and if you are running a 32-bit application the virtual address you can address is at most 32-bits, which is 4GB... one eighth the size of your 32GB array!